# Display a ListView inside a TabView with Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, listview, tabview

I am using Django tabination to display several tabs using class based views. All classes used to display tabs inherit from MainNavigationBaseTab class:

```
class MainNavigationBaseTab(TabView):
    """Base class for all main navigation tabs."""
    tab_group = 'main_navigation'
    tab_classes = ['main-navigation-tab']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainNavigationBaseTab, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main'] = 'maintenance'
        return context

    @property
    def tab_classes(self):
        """If user is logged in, set ``logged_in_only`` class."""
        classes = super(MainNavigationBaseTab, self).tab_classes[:]
        if self.current_tab.request.user.is_authenticated():
            classes += ['logged_in_only']
        return classes
```

In one of the tabs I want to display a list of contacts derived from ListView class:

```
class ListContactView(ListView):
  model = Contact
  template_name = 'main_tab.html'
```

My approach was to derive the MainTab class from both MainNavigationBaseTab and ListContactView:

```
class MainTab(ListContactView, MainNavigationBaseTab):
    _is_tab = True
    tab_id = 'main'
    tab_label = _('Main')
    template_name = 'main_tab.html'
```

however the problem I have with this approach is that get_context_data() method is called on wrong class and object_list is not found in context when I try to display the tab. Below is the full error message I am getting:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in get
>     157.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File "/home/.../views.py" in get_context_data
>     27.         context = super(PatientListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File "/home/.../views.py" in get_context_data
>     37.         context = super(MainNavigationBaseTab, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabination/views.py" in
>   get_context_data
>     145.         context = super(TabView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py"
>   in get_context_data
>     130.         queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /mainview/ Exception Value:
>   'MainTab' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Could someone tell me how to display the list of contacts using a model stored in a database with Django tabination ?

thanks
Bogdan

Comment: have you tried writing a get_context_data for the MainTab class also?